# Mod rewrite - distribute unlimited domains to subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdirectory

I'm wondering if it's possible to redirect N domains to subfolders with a single rewriterule.

I mean something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /${REMOTE_HOST}/$1 [L]
```

For exmaple:

```
http://x.y.z/path -> /y.z/path
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

It's new for me that I can use the capturing group of a RewriteCond in the replacement of a RewriteRule...